# pandas dataframe sort_values on multiple columns did not work all the time

Tags: string, sorting, pandas

I'm having this 2 pandas dataframes, I tried to sort them the same way, but getting different result

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'a':'4','b':'23'},{'a':'3', 'b':'10'},{'a':'2','b':'88'},{'a':'2', 'b':'29'},{'a':'2','b':'12'},{'a':'1','b':'284'}, {'a':'1','b':'24'}, {'a':'3','b':'1'}])

print(df.sort_values(['a', 'b']))

df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'c1':'3','c2':'10'},{'c1':'2', 'c2':'30'},{'c1':'1','c2':'20'},{'c1':'2','c2':'15'},{'c1':'2','c2':'100'},{'c1':'1','c2':'11'}])

print(df1.sort_values(['c1', 'c2']))
```

the first one returns, which is expected

```
   a    b
6  1   24
5  1  284
4  2   12
3  2   29
2  2   88
7  3    1
1  3   10
0  4   23
```

the 2nd one returns

```
   c1   c2
5  1   11
2  1   20
4  2  100
3  2   15
1  2   30
0  3   10
```

I would think it would return

```
  c1   c2
5  1   11
2  1   20
4  2   15
3  2   30
1  2  100
0  3   10
```

can someone tell me why they behave differently?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is problem your data are strings, not numbers, so are sorted alphabetically.

Solution is convert column to `int`:

```
df1['c2'] = df1['c2'].astype(int)
print(df1.sort_values(['c1', 'c2']))
  c1   c2
5  1   11
2  1   20
3  2   15
1  2   30
4  2  100
0  3   10
```

Comment: Hi, jezreal,  thanks for the reply.  In my case, I need to sort by multiple columns, some of them are strings.  Is there a way that sort_values of dataframe can behave the same way as ORDER BY in sql?

Comment: Hmmm, not so easy. But do you need sort string numbers (in your sample) like numbers? Is impossible convert to numbers?

Comment: the example I gave here is for demo only.  I'm aware that if I gave int for those numbers, sort will works.  In my real case, I have dataframe from excel sheet, and a dataframe from sql query.  I've convert the sql query dataframe into string (using applymap(str)), because some number has leading or trailing zeroes.  I guess I need to convert the number columns back to int and sort both dataframes.  thanks.

Comment: Hmmm, without real data it is not easy, but in my opinion simpliest is convert all int first `df[['int_col1','int_col2','int_col3']] = df[['int_col1','int_col2','int_col3']].astype(int)`, then sort and last convert to numeric back. `df[['int_col1','int_col2','int_col3']] = df[['int_col1','int_col2','int_col3']].astype(str)`. But maybe there is another problem, do you remove trailing 0 by convert to `str` ? Is it correct way? Is impossible first sort and then convert to `str`?

Comment: Yes, I remove the trailing ".0" from Oracle after conver to 'str' using something like   df['int_col1'].replace(to_replace="(\d+)\.0", value=r"\1", regex=True, inplace=True)    thanks jezrael.